calculate angle and distance between two sets of points
I have a start point (A, B, ...) and several end points (1, 2, 3, ...) connected to the start point, and I want to get the angle between a given start point and its associated end points, and the distance from the start point to each end point, using R.
A visual example (not representing the dataset below):

And the table I have looks like this:
start_point start_point_x   start_point_y   end_point   end_point_x end_point_y
A           1               1               A_1         1.5         1.7
A           1               1               A_2         1.3         2
A           1               1               A_3         1.69        0.63
A           1               1               A_4         2.45        1.32
B           2               2               B_1         3.24        2.15
B           2               2               B_2         1.97        1.85
B           2               2               B_3         2.15        3.89

And the structure:
> dput(df)
structure(list(start_point = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B"), start_point_x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), start_point_y = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), end_point = c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", 
"A_4", "B_1", "B_2", "B_3"), end_point_x = c(1.5, 
1.3, 1.69, 2.45, 3.24, 1.97, 2.15), end_point_y = c(1.7, 2, 0.63, 
1.32, 2.15, 1.85, 3.89)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

I would like to obtain two extra columns (angle and distance) in the same table, looking like this (made up values):
start_point start_point_x   start_point_y   end_point   end_point_x end_point_y angle   distance
A           1               1               A_1         1.5         1.7         -            2
A           1               1               A_2         1.3         2           30         2.5
A           1               1               A_3         1.69        0.63        25         1.7
A           1               1               A_4         2.45        1.32        47        0.89
B           2               2               B_1         3.24        2.15        -            4
(...)

Where the angle is between Point A_1 - Point A - Point A_2, and then Point A_2 - Point A - Point A_3, and so on.
What I've tried so far
I have seen the example proposed here but this doesn't seem to be doing what I would want because it's not considering the 3rd point (if I'm understanding it correctly). Also not sure what the output units are.
I've tried this function and this one works. But I'm not sure how to apply it to my current dataset.
So far, I have this code within a loop (by start_point), following this:
# my_split_ds_i is the dataset filtering `df` by `start_point`    
my_split_ds_i$angle <- apply(X = my_split_ds_i, 
                                  MARGIN = 1, 
                                  FUN = function(x) LearnGeom::Angle(A=c(x[['end_point_x']],x[['end_point_y']]),
                                                          B=c(x[['start_point_x']],x[['start_point_y']]),
                                                          C=c(lag(x[['end_point_x']]),lag(x[['end_point_y']]))))

But I get this error from the function:
Error in A[[1]] - B[[1]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Which I think is connected to the fact that the function is obtaining the column (which here is more than one value, while in their example this function is applied to only one row), or with the fact that lag() creates NAs. But I didn't manage to figure out how to fix this.
Any suggestions are welcome!
